# Android: Don't show autosuggest list when item is selected

Tags: android, autocomplete, autosuggest

I was doing some stuff using autocomplete textview in my application. I'm getting suggestion when user types anything. But, I have one query, when user types and taps on the suggested list on the autocomplete textview, then more suggestions comes up. I want to limit the search results when user taps on the list and don't want to show more options there. How can I overcome this situation.

This is my full class, which I'm working on:

```
public class WikiSuggestActivity extends Activity {
public String data;
public List<String> suggest;
public AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
public ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            String newText = s.toString();
            new getJson().execute(newText);
        }

    });

}

class getJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
        String newText = key[0];
        newText = newText.trim();
        newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
        try {
            HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="
                            + newText + "&limit=8&namespace=0&format=json");
            ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
            suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.getJSONArray(1).length(); i++) {
                String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONArray(1).getString(i);
                suggest.add(SuggestKey);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, suggest);
                autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class WikiSuggestActivity extends Activity {
    public String data;
    public List<String> suggest;
    public AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;
    public TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            String newText = s.toString();
            new getJson().execute(newText);
        }
    };
    public boolean watch = true;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
        autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener( mTextWatcher );
        autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                autoComplete.removeTextChangedListener( mTextWatcher );
                aAdapter.clear();
                watch = false;
            }
        });
    }

    class getJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
            String newText = key[0];
            newText = newText.trim();
            newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
            try {
                HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(
                        "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="
                                + newText + "&limit=8&namespace=0&format=json");
                ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
                suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.getJSONArray(1).length(); i++) {
                    String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONArray(1).getString(i);
                    suggest.add(SuggestKey);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            if( watch )
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, suggest);
                        autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for rplying so quick, but did you understand my question. I do want to show the list, when user taps on the suggestion. In my case the list is displayed again when user taps the suggestion.

Comment: Tried your answer but still dropdown is coming after I have selected the suggestion. I want to dismiss the dropdown when user selects anything from that.

Comment: I have tried this to but it was not much of a help.
autoComplete.dismissDropDown();

Comment: @Anupam Now, I've tested it, and it's works. Just `onTextChanged` was called earlier than `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: +1 for that. But, I have done some testing with this, clicking on the item populated and the dropdown list vanishes, perfect. But when you delete the typed word and write again the suggestion goes off. This time suggestion list does not populate. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @Anupam It's simple. Inside `onItemClick` you may add another `TextWatcher`, that will be watching if key pressed again. I'll try it later and write results.